# Keras Two (or multiple) outputs with Custom losses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i'd like to train my image data and 201 label vector data through a VAE model.

First of all, I created a simple auto-encoder model by referring to the link below and produced results. (and loss functions were 'mse' and 'binary_crossentropy')

https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

The result was satisfactory. However, I wanted to go back to the VAE model, and I finished sampling at the late space after encoder.
and Here's the problem.
like a auto encoder, the following declaration was made in the comfile.

```
VAE.compile(optimizer=opt,metrics=['acc',],loss={'sptm':'mse','recon':vae_loss})
```

Here, the following error occurred:

```
ValueError: ('Could not interpret loss function identifier:', <tf.Tensor 'Mean_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>)
```

I tried to Google it, but it all failed to execute the code.
As in the image attached, I would like to apply **mse loss to sptm** and **vae_loss to recon img**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW1Zv.png)

How can I use custom loss for models with two outputs?

Comment: It seems the problem is on your `vae_loss` function. Could you please show how did you implement it?

Comment: @BatuhanBardak yes. that was my problem. I actually solved this problem today. I used custom loss without functioning it, but I could start learning by functionizing it. Thank you for your interest in my problem. Have a nice day.